# Issue Queries/Prepared Statements from within a class

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a class I am working with:

```
class SlayWork
{
     public function AllowDB ()
     {
          $MySQLi = new mysqli(DBAHost, DBAUsername, DBAPassword, DBADB);
     }
}
```

How would I communicate with my database from another public function from within this class? example:

```
public function GetTest ()
{
   $Var = $MySQL->prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
   $Var->execute();
   $Var->bind_result($ID, $Uname);
}
```

adding

```
public $MySQLi  = new mysqli(DBAHost, DBAUsername, DBAPassword, DBADB);
```

without the public function returns:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Error\ClassWork.php on line 16

adding `global` with the public function returns:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Error\ClassWork.php on line 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty property like `private $db_conn;`. Then create a class construct and inside it create the connection like this:

```
$this->db_conn = new mysqli(DBAHost, DBAUsername, DBAPassword, DBADB);
```

Now every time you instantiate your class you are connected to the database and all methods you call will be able to communicate with your db.

## Example:

*class.php*

```
class Database {
    private $db_conn;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db_conn = new mysqli(DBAHost, DBAUsername, DBAPassword, DBADB);
    }

    public function GetTest () {
       $Var = $this->db_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
       $Var->execute();
       $Var->bind_result($ID, $Uname);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still causing me trouble, where do I impliment this? This is one of my projects to get me and a team of coders to OOP

Comment: Check it now. Edited.

Comment: and this can be called from within my ClassWork Class and from the outside by `$Var = new ClassWork();` and `$DB= $Var->db_conn;` then `$var = $DB->prepare();`

Comment: I made `$db_conn` private so it can be accessed within the class only, so if you want it to be changeable from the outside too use the `public` keyword instead of `private`.